# LazyVerticalGrid or LazyColumn clips the content horizontally when using contentPadding

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have a case that I need to put a LazyRow inside a LazyVerticalGrid but when I set a contentPadding in grid it clips the lazy row horizontally. If I remove it than I will need to manually give padding to grid items but it will create double padding between them so I am not sure how to approach this.
This also happens with LazyColumn but with LazyColumn we can give padding to items and it wouldnt be a problem.
Any idea about it?

[image]